# How can I address being paid less than minimum due to forced unpaid overtime?

Tags: human-resources, negotiation, united-kingdom, law

My question is about being paid a salaried wage. My contract says I must work a minimum of 50 hours a week to receive my monthly or annual salary.

Over the last year I worked enough hours over that my salary does not meet the  the National Minimum Wage. Is there anything I can do to request compensation so that my salary pays me at least the minimum wage?

Comment: Would be great to know the country you're in. In the UK, being paid below the minimum wage is illegal. A contract that forces you to work 50 hours a week is most likely illegal. Whether legal or not, your employer is a scumbag and you should urgently look for a job somewhere else.

Comment: @gnasher729 absolutely the governments site explains this 

https://www.gov.uk/minimum-wage-different-types-work/paid-an-annual-salary

Comment: Talk to a lawyer (not a barrister in this case).

Comment: The government used to have a web portal to report employers who were paying under the minimum wage (a criminal offence, by the way).  The current regime has removed this and the website simply advises people to contact ACAS to seek arbitration.

https://www.gov.uk/pay-and-work-rights

Comment: Acas have a help line. I've called them and found it to be useful, with knowledgeable staff . 0300 123 1100.

Answer (score 4):

There's an EU-wide maximum number of work hours. It's 48 hours on average. You're apparently expected to work 50 *minimum*, which is ludicrous. And not making the minimum wage to boot.

The government maintains a portal that distills a few key things to know about labor laws:

- https://www.gov.uk/maximum-weekly-working-hours
- https://www.gov.uk/national-minimum-wage-rates
- https://www.gov.uk/overtime-your-rights

In addition to reading the above, you should talk to a lawyer and/or a labor union. (Also, consider looking for a new job. Life's too short to work for snakes.)